# PowerBuilder Vertex connection

Tags: connection, powerbuilder, vertex

I am trying to connect to a Vertex tax database using PowerBuilder 11.1 and am having problems with the following code.

I think I am connecting correctly since the return codes for `ls_status_text = loo_xmlhttp.StatusText` is 200 and `ll_status_code =  loo_xmlhttp.Status` is OK.

When I get the return value from the `ls_response_text = loo_xmlhttp.ResponseText` code the return value is the MOTW message.

---

I am expecting the following code to send the ls_get_url (which contains the xml to be sent to vertex) and receive a large xml in return with calculated tax rates based off the ls_get_url xml.  What I am getting is ls_status_text = 'OK' and ll_Status_code = 200 ( anything >300 is a problem).

// Get request
    loo_xmlhttp.open ("GET",ls_get_url , false)
    loo_xmlhttp.send()

```
//Get response
ls_status_text = ''
ls_status_text = loo_xmlhttp.StatusText
ll_status_code =  loo_xmlhttp.Status
```

after the above block of code runs successfully the following code runs:

```
    if ll_status_code >= 300 then
        MessageBox("HTTP POST Request Failed", ls_response_text)
    else
        //Get the response we received from the web server
        ls_response_text = loo_xmlhttp.ResponseText

        MessageBox("POST Request Succeeded", ls_response_text)
    end if
```

### I get the "POST Request Succeeded" messagebox but the ls_response_text contains the Mark Of The Web syntax.

Do you have any ideas that can help me along?

Thanks!

```
String ls_get_url, ls_post_url
String ls_post_variables, ls_response
String ls_response_text, ls_status_text
long   ll_status_code
OleObject loo_xmlhttp

//include parameters on the URL here for get parameters

ls_get_url = 'http://10.1.1.65:8095/vertex-ui/vertextcc.jsp'

try
    //Create an instance of our COM object
    loo_xmlhttp = CREATE oleobject
    loo_xmlhttp.ConnectToNewObject( 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP')

    // Get request
    loo_xmlhttp.open ("GET",ls_get_url , false)
    loo_xmlhttp.send()

    //Get response
    ls_status_text = ''
    ls_status_text = loo_xmlhttp.StatusText
    ll_status_code =  loo_xmlhttp.Status

    //Check HTTP Response code for errors
    if ll_status_code >= 300 then
        MessageBox("HTTP GET Request Failed", ls_response_text)
    else
        //Get the response we received from the web server
        ls_response_text = loo_xmlhttp.ResponseText
        MessageBox("GET Request Succeeded", ls_response_text)
    end if

    ls_post_url = 'http://10.1.1.65:8095/vertex-ui/vertextcc.jsp'
    ls_post_variables = "I add my custom xml here - I can run it in the vertex software and      the xml executes fine"

    loo_xmlhttp.open ("POST",ls_post_url, false)
    loo_xmlhttp.send(ls_post_variables)

    //Get response
    ls_status_text = loo_xmlhttp.StatusText
    ll_status_code =  loo_xmlhttp.Status

    //Check HTTP Response code for errors

    if ll_status_code >= 300 then
        MessageBox("HTTP POST Request Failed", ls_response_text)
    else
        //Get the response we received from the web server
        ls_response_text = loo_xmlhttp.ResponseText

        MessageBox("POST Request Succeeded", ls_response_text)
    end if

    loo_xmlhttp.DisconnectObject()

catch (RuntimeError rte)
    MessageBox("Error", "RuntimeError - " + rte.getMessage())
end try
```

Comment: I cannot understand exactly what is the problem. What do you get, what do you expect ? What is the line (if any) in your excerpt where the problem occurs ?

Answer (score 0):

There's an On Demand Vertex service. I hit the .../vertex-ui/vertextcc.jsp address on port 80 and got a login prompt. So it appears you need to Post the login data before you start shoving XML at it. I couldn't look any farther as I don't have an account. I don't know what the server would give you after you log in, but if it's a page you can paste XML into, you could install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and see exactly what belongs in the Post. Fiddler will also show you what Microsoft XMLHTTP is posting and what the server is sending back.